# Request to reopen question 372203

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[What's the difference between one-dash and two-dashes for command prompt parameters?](https://superuser.com/q/372203/100787) was closed as 'not constructive'. I disagree. There *is* a difference, as explained on [Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/what-does-double-dash-mean):

> A double dash (--) is used in bash built-in commands
>   and many other commands to signify the end of command options, after
>   which only positional parameters are accepted.

Comment: I'd reopen it, but not based on the question you linked to – it deals about the trailing double dash, not the one used for actual parameters.

Comment: Ah. I misread the question. I was only focused on the double dash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was reopened. Thank you, ♦!